# Xcode7 scene editor SKSpriteNode custom class

Tags: skspritenode, xcode7, sknode

Can anyone tell me if I am doing this right? Using Xcode 7.beta6 I am setting up a `SKSpriteNode` Custom Class in the Xcode scene editor.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ZoneNode: SKSpriteNode {
    var zoneID: Int = 0
}
```

I have the `SKSpriteNode` in the scene editor set as follows:

[image]

***NOTE***: I have tried this both with and without the Module name, it does not seem to make any difference as far as I can see.

Everything seems to work, there a 8 `SKSpriteNode`s in the scene but only 2 `ZoneNodes`, when I list all the children in the scene I get the following output.

```
// CODE
let allChildren = self.children
for eachChild in allChildren {
    if eachChild.isKindOfClass(ZoneNode) {
        print("CHILD: \(eachChild)")
    }
}
```

.

```
// OUTPUT
CHILD: <SKSpriteNode> name:'CUSTOM_SPRITE_2' texture:['nil'] position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{100, 100} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00
CHILD: <SKSpriteNode> name:'CUSTOM_SPRITE_1' texture:['nil'] position:{0, 0} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{100, 100} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00
SKIPPED: 6
```

I understand the `self.children` returns an SKNode array `[SKNode]`, if I downcast a node to `ZoneNode` everything works as expected and I can easily access the property `zoneID`.

```
let thisZoneNode = eachChild as! ZoneNode
thisZoneNode.zoneID = 123
```

I am a little confused as to why the print lists the nodes as `<SKSpriteNode>` and not as `ZoneNode`, although this might simply be referring back to the base class I originally subclassed, anyone any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

The "custom class" feature doesn't work in Xcode beta 6, but it seems to work correctly in the GM release ([7A218](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/))